# Using Unclead's yii2-multiple-input issue with radio buttons

Tags: php, yii2, radio-button, yii-widgets

I have an issue with Unclead's yii2-multiple-input widget i'm using the multi column to add an input field with a radio button when i add a row then it create a input field with a radio button and due to different name they all radios behave like checkbox.

Please give me solution so that radio button has same name for all rows.

Here is my source code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'schedule')->widget(MultipleInput::className(), [
'max' => 10,
'columns' => [
[
'name' => 'answer_choice',
'enableError' => true,
'title' => 'Answer Choice'

],
[


'name'  => 'Correct_ans',
'type'  => 'radio',
'title' => 'Correct Answer'

]
```

]

]);
?>

Comment: What have you tried, you should provide sample code, check out http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Please add your code, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Example :  echo $form->field($model, 'Yourfield')->radioList($listdata, ['inline' => true, 'separator' => '    '])->label(FALSE);

Comment: Guys i edited my question please check the source code

Comment: Hello all please give me the solution so i can proceed